# gcsfs.retry.HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage

I have a Python API application that accesses data from Google Cloud Storage via a service account. It works perfectly fine when I run the code on my PC, but when I containerize the application and try to access an endpoint, I get the following traceback:

```
gcsfs.retry.HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)., 401
```

I've seen options to deploy the container on Cloud run, but I do not have access rights (I'm using a service account).

Is there a way I can containerize an app that accesses cloud storage using a service account?

Answer (score 1):

You can containerize your application and run it on Cloud Run while continuing to use a service account to access Google Cloud Storage.

1. You can use a service account that has permissions to access Google Cloud Storage bucket. Particularly `storage.objects.get`. [Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam)
2. For your application, create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).
3. If you haven't already, include the `google-auth` and `google-cloud-storage` packages in your `requirements.txt` file. These packages enable Google Cloud Storage access and service account authentication for your application. [Authenticate Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#service-accounts)
4. Use the `google.auth` module to authenticate with your service account in your Python code. [Python Client for Google Cloud Storage](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html).
5. Build and deploy your container to Cloud Run using `gcloud` command. To enable service account authentication for your application, be careful to set the `GOOGLE APPLICATION CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the location of your service account key file. [Deploy a Python service to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy)